# Can you have a stand alone directive in Angular 2

Tags: javascript, angularjs-directive, angular, angular2-template, angularjs-components

I'm playing around with Angular 2, What I'd like to do is to have a stand alone directive directly assigned to an element within the HTML. Is this possible?

Directive:

```
import {Directive, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';
@Directive({
    selector: '[Slidernav]'
})
export class Slidernav {
    constructor(private element: ElementRef) {
        console.log('Slider Run');
    }
}
```

and I would assign it to any HTML element like so:

```
<div slidernav>Some content</div>
```

The reason why I'm asking is because I don't want to set the template with HTML  that already exists in the DOM using a Component.

**EDIT**

So based on the responses, this is the component

Component Slider

```
 import {Component, View, ElementRef} from 'angular2/core';
 @Component({
    selector: 'Slider',
    template: '<ng-content></ng-content>'
 })
 export class Slider {
     constructor(private element: ElementRef) {
         console.log('Slider');
     }
}
```

index.html

```
<Slider>
    <div>hello world</div>
</Slider>
```

I would be expecting the Div to remain within Slider with the content hello world. AFAIK that's how it should work based on what i've been reading about Transclusion. But the console error is:

```
Error: The component Slider has 1 <ng-content> elements, but only 0 slots were provided.
```

Comment: I don't really understand what you try to accomplish. Sounds like a component with a template with just `<ng-content></ng-content>` does what you want.

Comment: I don't see anything wrong. To me this looks like a bug. Just out of curiosity. Could you please try `<Slider><div>hello world</div></Slider>` (without spaces or line breaks)?

Comment: I've updated it and it's still throwing an error.

Comment: I guess this calls for a Plunker repo.

Comment: https://plnkr.co/UH42bVv93Fedrre7GKFI

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should work except that Angular templates are case sensitive

```
selector: '[Slidernav]'
...
<div slidernav>Some content</div>
```

should either be

```
selector: '[Slidernav]'
...
<div Slidernav>Some content</div>
```

or

```
selector: '[slidernav]'
...
<div slidernav>Some content</div>
```

besides that you might want to use a component with a template like

```
template: '<ng-content></ng-content>`
```

This way your component just displays the HTML the parent provided as children to your component

Comment: Hi, `template: '<ng-content></ng-content>` is throwing a console error: `Error: The component Slider has 1 <ng-content> elements, but only 0 slots were provided.`. It is strange because I don't know what slots means in this case? I've kept this component simple. It's called Slider, the selector is 'Slider', in the html I've got this code `<Slider> <div>hello world</div> </Slider>`.

Comment: Can you please edit your question with the code of your slider and how you use it?

Comment: I think I start to understand what you mean by standalone - not inside another Angular component? AFAIK `<ng-content>` currently doesn't work on the root component (not sure if this is planned to change).

Comment: Shame, although it does seem like a limitation, well to me anyway

Comment: You'd have to looks it up in the GitHub issues. I think I saw a discussion about this. It's the same with `@Input()` which aren't working on root components as well.